# Hive - how to check if a numeric columns have number/decimal?

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, numeric

I am trying to generate a hive query which will take multiple numeric column names and check whether it is has numeric values. If the column has numeric values then the output should be (column name,true) else if the field has NULL or some string value the output should be (column name,false)

```
SELECT distinct (test_nr1,test_nr2) FROM test.abc WHERE (test_nr1,test_nr2) not like '%[^0-9]%';

SELECT distinct test_nr1,test_nr2 from test.abc limit 2;
test_nr1   test_nr2
NULL    81432269
NULL    88868060

the desired output should be :
test_nr1  false
test_nr2  true
```

Since test_nr1 is a decimal field and it has NULL values, it should output false.

Appreciate valuable suggestions.

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cast` function. It returns `NULL` when the value can not not be cast to numeric.

For example:

```
select case when cast('23ccc' as double) is null then false else true end as IsNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use character class pattern matching syntax here, and it doesn't work in every SQL implementation IIRC, however, regexp matching works in most, if not all, SQL implementations.

Considering you're using hive, this should do it:

```
SELECT ('test_nr1', test_nr1 RLIKE '\d'), ('test_nr2', test_nr2 RLIKE '\d') FROM test.abc;
```

You should remember that regexp matching is very slow in SQL though.